# Leaflet- Finding the Zoom Level Of Bounds Without Using a Map Instance

Tags: zooming, leaflet

**What I'm trying To DO**:

I'm in a bit of a pinch where I need to be able to **find the leaflet zoom levels of multiple shapes without creating a map instance and moving all around it with `map.fitBounds()`**.

---

**The 2 possible solutions that I'm stuck on:**

1) **I tried making mock/temp map to gain access to the `map.fitBounds()`** functionality and simulate `map.fitBounds()`

-But is not working because the map needs a div container to be instantiated.

2) **I've looked for ways to programmatically calculate the leaflet zoom.**

-I haven't found any resources out there on how to do that.

If you have any strategies to help me convert this raw data to their leaflet counterparts that would be AWESOME!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a `L.Map` instance with an element that's not appended to the DOM:

```
new L.Map(document.createElement('div'), {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0
});
```

Problem is that in order to calculate the bounds the responsible method will need to know the size of the map. To get the size it will call the `getSize` method of `L.Map` but that will always return a size of `{x:0, y:0}` since the map's element is not appended to the DOM. You could override the `getSize` method to return a size:

```
L.Map.include({
    getSize: function () {
        return new L.Point(400, 300);
    }
});

var map = new L.Map(document.createElement('div'), {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0
});

console.log(map.getSize()); // o.Point {x: 400, y: 300}
```

Now you can call the `getBoundsZoom` of `L.Map` using your `L.LatLngBounds`:

```
L.Map.include({
    getSize: function () {
        return new L.Point(400, 300);
    }
});

var map = new L.Map(document.createElement('div'), {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0
});

var featureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup([
    new L.Marker([0,-45]),
    new L.Marker([0,45])
]);

var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(featureGroup.getBounds());
```

Needless to say, when later on using the derived zoomlevel on a real map, it will only be correct if the map is the size you predefined in the `getSize` method. Also don't forget to restore the `getSize` method if you plan on using `L.Map` without reloading.

Comment: I'm trying it out now. I'll let everyone know how it goes. Thx in advance though for a boss looking answer!@IH8

Comment: One question though, Can the work-around solution be extended to work just an array of bounds, or do I need to create a `FeatureGroup` of markers? Just curious, cause that would be clean.

Comment: Just threw that in there as a quick way to generate some bounds on the fly. Doesn't matter how you create the L.LatLngBounds object.

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for. Sorry for the typo, freehanded this. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to set the zoom to show a circle with variable radius well fit in the container DIV, here the code I used:

```
    // r is the radius in meters (for example 2km => 2000)
    circle.setRadius(r);

    // <div> size containing leaflet map
    var width = 300;
    var height = 220;

    // you have to use the MIN of them if you want the circle fit in    
    metresPerPixel = r * 2 / height;

    // here the zoom level you have to use
    z = (Math.log((40075016.686 * Math.cos(map.getCenter().lat * Math.PI/180))/metresPerPixel))/Math.log(2)-8;

    mymap.setZoom(z.toFixed(2),{animate:false});
```

Be sure you set zoomSnap when creates map to the needed value (I set it to the minimun 0.1 for better results)

The formula is the result of clear z from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels